# Не записывается строка в файл

Tags: файлы, golang

Создаю файл. Пишу в него данные. При этом файл остаётся пустым. В чём причина?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("1.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    writer.WriteString("12345")
}
```

Comment: А если добавить `writer.Flush()`?

Comment: @gil9red да, так и сделал. Решилось. Спс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После записи в буфер нужно записать данные в файл: `writer.Flush()`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("1.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    writer.WriteString("12345")
    writer.Flush()
}
```